# How to delete all data of uninstalled themes and plugins?

Tags: plugins, themes

how can I delete all the data left in the database or some files left over from old themes or plugins uninstalled from my WordPress site?
For example, before I had Avada theme, now that I've uninstalled it, I've noticed that I remain all the various custom fields and meta data that are present in the theme that is no longer there?  is there any solution?  even if it fails to clean up entirely that's fine!

Comment: This depends on the theme or plugin being used. Some provide an option to delete all their data or do this automatically upon removing. Others don't have this feature. Please reach out to the theme or plugin developer to see if they provide such a feature.